# Nginx regex redirect not working

Tags: nginx

I have some old urls of the form:

```
https://website.com/ptlf/rest-of-url/
```

I have eliminated the unnecessary `ptlf` from my urls and need to redirect old urls to the new format.  I have tried both of the following Nginx regex redirects, but neither works when I enter an old url with the `ptlf` in it.

```
rewrite ^/ptlf/(.+) https://website.com/$1 permanent;

location ~ ^/ptlf/(.+) {
    return 301 https://website.com/$1;
}
```

It just returns a Not Found error message with the `ptlf` still in the url.  Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

> rewrite ^/ptlf(.*)$ $1 last;

Comment: I discovered my problem - a dumb mistake on my part:  I had the redirect in the wrong server block within the `.conf` file.  For some reason, your rewrite doesn't work, but both of the two redirects that I had tried now work.

Comment: hey you try to replace the ptlf with pg like so: rewrite    ^(.*)ptlf(.*)$    $1pg$2;